# How to test a test case?

Tags: go, testing

My program has a blacklist feature where a file lists some conditions to exclude. The file is called `blacklist.yaml`.

This file is brought to production<sup>(*)</sup> together with the main code (into a docker container) and before anything else I want to make sure that the structure of the file is correct.

To this end I wrote:

```
func TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect(t *testing.T) {}
```

which has `blacklist.yaml` hardcoded and will be run as part of the **deployment process to abort it if there are syntax errors** in the structure (and therefore leaving the existing container intact and running). That part is fine.

I now would like to *"test the test"* - that is to write a test `Test_TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect` that will check if `TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect` is actually correct, takes into account all cases, edge cases, etc.

To do this I have a `blacklist_test.yaml` which has a range of correct and incorrect structures. I would like to run `TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect` against that list to make sure it catches possible issues correctly.

**My problem:** `TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect` has `blacklist.yaml` hardcoded. I could pass a parameter with the filename to the routine that actually reads the file (I did that in the example code below) but that would require to **pass this parameter** independently to `TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect` and to `Test_TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect`.

It seems however that passing variables to tests is not possible. What is the standard way to approach such a problem in Go?

The code I have so far is below (mostly to show the logic around importing the YAML data)

```golang
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "testing"
)

func TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect(t *testing.T) {
    blacklist := readBlacklist("blacklist.yaml")
    for _, entry := range blacklist {
        log.Info().Msgf("testing pattern %v of type %v", entry.Match, entry.Type)
        if entry.Type == "exact" || entry.Type == "regex" {
            log.Info().Msg("type is correct")
        } else {
            t.Errorf("type %v is not known", entry.Type)
            continue
        }
        if entry.Type == "regex" {
            _, err := regexp.Compile(entry.Match)
            if err != nil {
                t.Errorf("incorrect match pattern: %v", err)
                continue
            }
        }
        log.Info().Msgf("pattern %v of type %v is correct", entry.Match, entry.Type)
    }
}

func Test_TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect() {
    // work in progress :)
}
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> The "production" is actually a home-grade program and the only person who can make mistakes is me. I mention this so that solutions that are not nuclear-plant-grade are acceptable.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I would consider embedding the .yaml file into your executable with a `//go:embed` directive, and only test its validity during the test phase, not at runtime.

Comment: @Flimzy: I am not sure what the difference would be? (I use embed in other code so I understand the concept - just not what this changes in the testing itself. The idea is nice, though, because this is one less file to copy)

Comment: It means that you know that the compiled version has already passed the tests, so you don't need to bother testing it at runtime.

Comment: Test functions can call other functions. Just factor out the testing code into a function and call it with different arguments from the Test* functions. Alternatively, use sub-tests as shown in [TableDrivenTests](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests).

Answer (score -2):

The easiest solution is simply not to use the `testing` package for your runtime test.  The `testing` package is meant for tests, not runtime.

So refactor `TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect` to something that doesn't depend on `testing`.  For example:

```golang
func TestIfBlacklistIsCorrect() error {
```

And put it in one of your non-`_test.go` files.

Then you can easily write a test for it as you wish.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, the test of the structure of the blacklist would be done at runtime (that is when the executable is actually started). What I would like is to test that structure prior to having built the executable, to abort if there are problems. (and have the currently running container not be replaced until the structure is fixed)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your requirements. I thought that's what you wanted.

Comment: Sorry for not having been clear. I updated my question with some more explicit statements.